# Rust crossbeam scope thread run async?

Tags: rust, async-await

I have an async function as follows which makes use of crossbeam thread scope:

```
 use crossbeam_utils::thread;
 use core_lib::request;

 pub async fn test(){
    // Will perform stuff here
    println!("will perform stuff here");
 }

 pub async fn initiate(){
    

    if let Ok(result) = request::Request::get_request().await{
        let message = result.message().iter();
        thread::scope(|s| {
            for r in message{
                log::debug!("Detected request id: {}",r.id());
                println!("{:?}",r.config());

                s.spawn(move |_| {
                    
                    log::info!("Processing request id: {}", r.id());
                    test().await;
                });

            }
        }).unwrap_or_default();
    }
}
```

If I compile this I get the following error:

```
   |
36 |                 s.spawn(move |_| {
   |                         -------- this is not `async`
...
48 |                     test().await;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
```

I tried to add async in the spawn as such but this block is never executed:

```
s.spawn(move |_| async move{
     log::info!("Processing request id: {}", request.id());
     test().await;
});
```

How do I execute my async test function in the `s.spawn`?

Comment: You need an executor to run your future on the spawned thread.